# Passing data from index method in controller to view.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a simple web application as a practice. I am trying to declare something in controller instead of using razor syntax to include the c# code in the view. I have tried viewbag but  it is not working.

My Index.chtml file has:

```
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) <br />

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)<br />



        if (item.Description.Length < 100)
        {
            var desshort = item.Description.Substring(0, item.Description.Length);
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => desshort) </p>
        }
        else
        {
            var desshort = item.Description.Substring(0, 100) + "....";
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => desshort) </p>
        }
```

I want to declare the if/else statement in my controller instead of the view itself.

I tried the following and I knew it was wrong before I even ran the application:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var query = from s in db.BookModels
                select s.Description;

  ****included if/else here *******
ViewBag.newDescription = query.ToString();

            return View(db.BookModels.ToList());
```

I am sure its something simple and I can't get it because I am so new to this. I really need some suggestion.

Comment: You can just use a `foreach` loop in the GET method to update the `Description` value - `var model= db.BookModels; foreach(var item in model){ if (item.Description.Length <100) { ..... // update value ...`. But why not just style you `<p>` element to display one line with ellipses?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you sir are a hero. I am trying  to avoid using css as much as possible but your guidance helped about the foreach look. Thank you :)